# Basic Representation Theory: One Dimensional Representation (Dummit and Foote 18.1 #2)

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I'm working on question 2 in 18.1 of Dummit and Foote.  The question states:

Let $\phi : G \to GL_n(F)$ be a matrix representation. Prove that the map $g \to det(\phi(g))$ is a degree 1 representation.

I know this is a basic question, but something just isn't clicking for me.

According to the definitions in D&F, A linear representation of $G$ is any homomorphism from $G$ into $GL(V)$ where $GL(V)$ is the group of nonsingular linear transformations from $V$ to itself (under composition).  The degree of the representation is the dimension of $V$.

For the dimension part, I was looking at $F$ as a degree one vector space over itself.  It's clear that $det(\phi(g)) \in F$, but I'm having trouble showing that $det(\phi(g))$ is a linear transformation from $F$ to itself.  I know this might be obvious, but I'm just not seeing it (or am I interpreting definitions incorrectly).

I was able to show that the map $g \to det(\phi(g))$ is a homomorphism without a hitch.

So essentially my question is how do I show that $det(\phi(g)) \in GL(F)$?

Comment: I'm sorry if the question is unclear.  I copied it directly from the book. The book defines a matrix representation of G to be a homomorphism from $G$ into $GL_n(F)$

Comment: Mind that $F^\times={\rm GL}_1(F)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any element of a field defines a linear transformation over the field. Let $x\in\Bbb F$, then we know that$-$from the field axioms$-$$x(a+b) = xa + xb$ and $x(\alpha a) = x\alpha a = \alpha x(a)$ for any $\alpha,a,b\in\mathbb{F}$. Thus multiplication by $x$ defines a linear map on $\Bbb F$. $g$ is invertible for any $g\in G$ so $\phi(g)$ is invertible, giving that $\det (\phi (g))\neq 0$ and so $\phi(g)\in GL(\Bbb F)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! $det(\phi(g)) \not= 0$ because $\phi(g) \in GL_2(F)$, right?$

Comment: Yep that's right. Since $\phi(g)$ is invertible, it has nonzero determinant.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of $\det \phi(g)$ as a $1\times 1$ matrix. A matrix corresponds to a linear transformation. In your case, the linear transformation $\det \phi(g)$ is just multiplication by $\det \phi(g)$, i.e., it maps $x \in F$ to $(\det \phi(g)) \cdot x \in F$.